# How to format big numbers to show million separator in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Given the following number `11452610,20` (11452610.20), I would like to format it like that: `11.452.610,20` (11,452,610.20)

I already tried to check "Use Thousands separator" but it only shows as `11452.610,20`

I'm using Windows 10. The language and localization setttings is `pt-br`

Comment: Where did you check this? If I use the normal Number format for Excel 2016 with "use thousand separator" it adds a separator every three characters. You could always use a custom format.

Comment: To get `11,452,610.20`, select cell/cells & apply either `Currency` or `Accounting` Number Format,, and keep Decimal place `2` ☺

Comment: see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e

Comment: Okay, guys, but none of that is actually working. Also, It would be better to be solved through a format expression, because the sheet will be generated dynamically. I'm trying to find something yet.

Comment: Go to Control Panel- Region- Additional formatting- check the Digit grouping of Numbers and Currency, make sure it is set: 123,456,789 https://imgur.com/a/YfE6gtX

Comment: @Lee indeed, that worked. Although I'm wondering it won't work on other computers, as I said, the file will be  created dynamically. Depending on the user's settings it won't looks good. Thank you however.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the cells to the respective format code: `#.###.##0,00` or similar.

Comment: It didn't work. I might have an environment issue.